# What is QoS in the context of Ethereum

Tags: ethereum, qos, go-ethereum

I often see this line in my go-ethereum output.

```
Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=5.329575339s  confidence=0.923 ttl=17.32992345s
```

What does QoS stand for and what is its purpose in Ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

It stands for Quality of Service. Geth keeps metrics on each of the peers you're connected to and the QoS metrics are used to tune for performance.